# Bootstrap 4.1, vertical navbar breakpoint not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a website with a horizontal navbar, works fine. At the appropriate breakpoints it collapses and you open it via the hamburger button.
Underneath I have a bootstrap row:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-2 px-0"> 
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="container show-not-on-mobile text-center pt-5"> <h5>Paintings</h5></div>
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light navbar-custom">
                            <div class="container mb-0 px-0 show-not-on-desktop">  
                                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/paintings">Paintings</a>
                                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mnav" aria-controls="mnav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <span class="fancy-toggler navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                  </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container mb-0 px-0">
                              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="malereinav">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto flex-column">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link active rounded" title="Movement" href="/paintings-movement">
                                            Movement
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                  </ul>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-10">                         
                Gallery Content shown with #Columns
                </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine, except this breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1280.98px){
    #columns[data-columns]::before {
        content: '3 .col-lg-4';
    }
}
```

At this breakpoint nothing happens with this navbar:
neither the navbar is displayed horizontally nor vertically.
Also no mobile version with hamburger is displayed.

No matter if I use navbar-expand-xl or navbar-expand-lg or navbar-expand-md ...

Maybe someone has an idea, I would be very happy.

Comment: Problem solved by myself, no more help needed. ;)

Comment: If you solve a problem, it might be helpful for other readers if you post a solution as a self-answer (you can later accept it). This also removes the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks.